# how to use fancybox in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, fancybox, nuxtjs

How do i use fancybox in nuxtjs. In vuejs it works fine but when i coded the same app on nuxtjs with fancybox it wont work properly. it just sends to the corresponding link

*nuxt.config.js*

```
export default {
...
head: {
...
script: [
      {
        href: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js",
        body: true
      },
      {
        href:
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js",
        body: true
      }
    ],
link: [
    ...
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css"
      },
     ...
    ]
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look https://github.com/mmoollllee/nuxt-starter-template

they have fancybox working with a nuxt start template that you can follow along with.

Comment: I'll check the link that you provide, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a Vue/Nuxt 3 component with `script setup`.

First create a `components/Fancybox.vue` file and put the code below in it:

```js
<script setup>
  import { Fancybox as NativeFancybox } from '@fancyapps/ui'

  import '@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.css'

  const props = defineProps({
    options: Object,
  })

  onMounted(() => {
    const opts = props.options || {}

    NativeFancybox.bind('[data-fancybox]', opts)

    return () => {
      NativeFancybox.destroy()
    }
  })
</script>

<template>
  <slot />
</template>
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```js
<template>
  <Fancybox :options="{}">
    <a href="./image.jpg" data-fancybox>
      <img src="./image.jpg" />
    </a>
  </Fancybox>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

here the the code that actually works

create fancyapps-ui.js in your plugings directory

```html
import { Fancybox } from "@fancyapps/ui";
import "@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox/fancybox.css";

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject("fancybox", {
    bind(container, selector, options) {
      Fancybox.bind(container, selector, options);
    },
    unbind(container) {
      Fancybox.unbind(container);
    },
    close() {
      Fancybox.close();
    },
    destroy() {
      Fancybox.destroy();
    },
  });
};
```

then create a Fancybox component

```html
<template>
  <div ref="container">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$fancybox.bind(this.$refs.container, "[data-fancybox]", {
      ...(this.options || {}),
    });
  },
  updated() {
    this.$fancybox.unbind(this.$refs.container);
    this.$fancybox.close();

    this.$fancybox.bind(this.$refs.container, "[data-fancybox]", {
      ...(this.options || {}),
    });
  },
  unmounted() {
    this.$fancybox.destroy();
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

now import fancybox component and use it:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Fancybox
      :options="{
        Carousel: {
          infinite: false,
        },
      }"
    >
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://lipsum.app/id/60/1600x1200">
        <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/60/200x150" width="200" height="150" />
      </a>
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://lipsum.app/id/61/1600x1200">
        <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/61/200x150" width="200" height="150" />
      </a>
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://lipsum.app/id/62/1600x1200">
        <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/62/200x150" width="200" height="150" />
      </a>
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://lipsum.app/id/63/1600x1200">
        <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/63/200x150" width="200" height="150" />
      </a>
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://lipsum.app/id/64/1600x1200">
        <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/64/200x150" width="200" height="150" />
      </a>
    </Fancybox>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import Fancybox from "~~/components/Fancybox.vue";
</script>
```